# Can't make an instance of the class in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm making a filter in Django, which takes URL of tweet as argument and returns a HTML code to display in browser. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, as Django complains that OEmbedConsumer is not callable. I believe it's either a random bug or a misunderstanding of how to use specific parts of framework on my side.

```
from django import template
from oembed import OEmbedConsumer, OEmbedEndpoint


register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def get_twitter_html(url):
  consumer = OEmbedConsumer()
  endpoint = OEmbedEndpoint('https://publish.twitter.com/oembed',
                          ['http://*.twitter.com/*',
                           'https://*.twitter.com/*'])
  consumer.addEndpoint(endpoint=endpoint)
  response = consumer(url)
  return response.html.replace('\\', '')
```

I have also tried to skip `()` but then addEndpoint complained about lack of `self`. Which is somewhat expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `oembed` and `OEmbedCosumer` supposed to be?

Comment: It will be helpful to share classes itself.

Comment: Please add the full traceback. I guess it's the line `response = consumer(url)` that causes the error. Have you read the docs for the oembed library that you are using? Could it be that it's `consumer.embed(url)` that is correct?

Comment: Once you have created an object `myobj = ClassName()`, you will call that object's methods `myobj.method_name(*args)`. If you try to call `myobj()` you will get that error message. (Unless the object has a `__call__` method)

Comment: It was exactly the error - syntax one. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to:

```
response = consumer.embed(url)
```

This is answered on a guess that you are using https://github.com/dokterbob/python-oembed for which in its readme file stands that it should be used like that.

Comment: Indeed it worked. I feel kinda stupid now. Thanks a lot!